# PHP Warnings: Parameter 2 and Invalid argument supplied foreach()

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am new to code and trying to identify errors on my site. It was created by a company using Php 5.6 and is now running Php 7.3

The debug file has two warnings (I've replaced the specific location with ...):

> PHP Warning:  Parameter 2 to WPE\Site_Preview::the_posts() expected to
>   be a reference, value given in ...wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288 PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   ...wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/plugin.php on line 1021

I've tried looking up the answers here, and the foreach error may be because it's not an array? But I'm not sure what an array is exactly, or how to check for it.  Any suggestions and advice would be gratefully received, sorry I'm new to this and teaching myself!

the code for the first error (Parameter 2 expected to be a reference)

```
// Avoid the array_slice if possible.
            if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
```

The code for the second error (invalid argument supplied foreach):

```
// Some paths might reject CDN completely -- if so, don't do CDN replacements.
    // In fact, UNDO any that were done by W3TC!
    $undo_cdn = false;
    foreach ( $wpe_no_cdn_uris as $re ) {
        if ( preg_match( '#' . $re . '#', $uri ) ) {
            $cdn_enabled = false;
            $undo_cdn    = true;
            break;
```

Comment: the code for the first error (Parameter 2 expected to be a reference) // Avoid the array_slice if possible.
    if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
     $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
    } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
    } else {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );

Comment: The code for the second error (invalid argument supplied foreach) . 

 // Some paths might reject CDN completely -- if so, don't do CDN replacements.
        // In fact, UNDO any that were done by W3TC!
        $undo_cdn = false;
        foreach ( $wpe_no_cdn_uris as $re ) {
            if ( preg_match( '#' . $re . '#', $uri ) ) {
                $cdn_enabled = false;
                $undo_cdn    = true;
                break;

Comment: This information needs to be in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: You definitely should start from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php ...

Comment: If the error is in any of the WPEngine files, DO NOT ALTER THEM. Reach out to WPE support to have them fix it. You should not modify their mu-plugin files.